# Unable to save data to composite Table Via Spring Data rest json post

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have 3 Tables in db

training 

   - training_id (pk)


user_profile

    - profile_id (pk)


-training_profile (composite table)
 
   - training_id
  
  - profile_id

I have already record in user_profile table having profile_id=44 and want to create new record for training table ,and also to associate this new training with already existing user_profile record which has id 44,but after post data is saved to training table but it is not inserted into lookup table user_training. 

My Object Classes Are 
 - Training Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "training", schema = "public")
public class Training implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "training_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long trainingId;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "trainings")
    private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>(0);

    @Column(name = "training_subject", length = 200)
    private String trainingSubject;

    public Training() {
    }

    public Long getTrainingId() {
        return this.trainingId;
    }

    public void setTrainingId(Long trainingId) {
        this.trainingId = trainingId;
    }


    public String getTrainingSubject() {
        return this.trainingSubject;
    }

    public void setTrainingSubject(String trainingSubject) {
        this.trainingSubject = trainingSubject;
    }


    public Set<UserProfile> getUserProfiles() {
        return this.userProfiles;
    }

    public void setUserProfiles(Set<UserProfile> userProfiles) {
        this.userProfiles = userProfiles;
    }
}
```

- UserProfile

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "user_profile", schema = "public")
  public class UserProfile implements java.io.Serializable {

  ```
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "profile_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Long profileId;

  @Column(name = "profile_description")
  private String profileDescription;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
  @JoinTable(name = "user_training", schema = "public", joinColumns = {
          @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                  @JoinColumn(name = "training_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
  private Set<Training> trainings = new HashSet<Training>(0);

  public UserProfile() {
  }


  public String getProfileDescription() {
      return this.profileDescription;
  }

  public void setProfileDescription(String profileDescription) {
      this.profileDescription = profileDescription;
  }


  public Set<Training> getTrainings() {
      return this.trainings;
  }

  public void setTrainings(Set<Training> trainings) {
      this.trainings = trainings;
  }
  ```

  }

My json post via postman
[image]

And Response I get

[image]

Response show that new training record inserted in table having training_id as 67 
No association found for this new saved training
[image]

again it created new record for training and does not associate with existing user profile , I post curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{ \"trainingSubject\" : \"Oracle\", \"userProfiles\":[\"/userProfiles/44\"] }" http://localhost:8080/api/trainings

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question with some corrections and try again? Put `@Id @GeneratedValue` to the right position infront of the id-fields. Both in `Training` and `UserProfile`.

Comment: `GET http://localhost:8080/api/userProfiles/44` does return something?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/api/userProfiles/44  ,kindly check i have added screen shot in question

Answer (score 0):

You could use the relative url assignment:

```
{
    "trainingSubject": "oracle",
    "userProfiles":["/userProfiles/44"]
}
```

Maybe also try with the full url: `http://localhost:8080/api/userProfiles/44`

**EDITED**

If you move the owning site of the `ManyToMany` relation to `Training` it will work with the above JSON. So currently the owner is allowed to set the realtions. If you do it like that:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_training"
, joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "profile_id") }
, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "training_id") })
private List<UserProfile> userProfiles = new ArrayList<>();
```

plus

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userProfiles")
private List<Training> trainings = new ArrayList<>();
```

`Training` owns the relation within `userProfiles`.

I think in your case it's the best option for now. Another option would be, when keeping the owner site at `UserProfile` on `transactions`, to update the relation there like:

```
PATCH http://localhost:8080/api/userProfiles/44
{
    "trainings": ["trainings/66", "trainings/67"]
}
```

But with this you would need multible rest calls (1. POST new training and get the new Id 2. GET current training list 3. PATCH trainings list with newly added training)

Last option would be to add the REST-controller on your own.

Complete files for the first approach:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Training implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long trainingId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_training"
    , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "profile_id") }
    , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "training_id") })
    private List<UserProfile> userProfiles = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "training_subject", length = 200)
    private String trainingSubject;


@Entity
@Table
public class UserProfile implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long profileId;

    @Column(name = "profile_description")
    private String profileDescription;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userProfiles")
    private List<Training> trainings = new ArrayList<>();


public interface TrainingRepository extends JpaRepository<Training, Long> {
}

public interface UserProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<UserProfile, Long> {
}
```

With the upper JSON this will work, I tested it. You will not see the correct result directly in the response of curl-POST. To see the added relation you must follow the `userProfiles`-link like `GET http://localhost:8080/transactions/<newId>/userProfiles`

Comment: this must work, maybe check with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929828/spring-rest-cannot-insert-rows-that-have-manytoone-column/42932108

Comment: I have updated accordingly to  curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{  \"trainingSubject\" : \Oracle\",  \"userProfile\" : "http://localhost:8080/api/userProfiles/44" }" http://localhost:8080/api/trainings     but it throw exception of com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('\\' (code 92)): expected a valid value (number, String

Comment: ok I put escape sequence and repost json,but again it give me same response as I have above in screen shot .

Comment: Ah okay.. After posting with the upper JSON (from the answer) is there something under `GET http://localhost:8080/api/training/67/userProfiles`? Relational child attributes in standard behaviour are not delivered when requesting the parent. A client then must follow the link.

Comment: the curl should look like this:  `curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{ \"trainingSubject\" : \Oracle\", \"userProfiles\":[\"/userProfiles/44\"] }" http://localhost:8080/api/training`

Comment: http://localhost:8080/api/training/67/userProfiles   It return me nothing or html exception as training having id 67 has no association with any userprofile.this association does not exist

Comment: While creating new record for training i do not know the id for training,my requirement is that when ever i add new record for training ,it should be associated to existing user_profile id.secondly how can i change the owner ship of object ,kindly suggest the right annotations for that to change ownership of entity.thanks

Comment: I updated the answer again. Hopefully now it's more understandable.

Comment: it through exception {"cause":{"cause":null,"message":"Unexpected character ('\\' (code 92)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n  "},"message":"Could not read document: Unexpected character ('\\' (code 92)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@670a5f47; line: 1, column: 24]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character

Comment: You used the curl I added? If so, there is a quote missing before "Oracle". If not you must check the command you've set up on your own. Keep fighting ;).

Comment: Thanks quote was missing , but again same problem as discussed earlier,i have add screen shot above after  curl post and response

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186824/spring-data-rest-how-to-perform-crud-on-manytomany-relation-composite-table-wi